# Low-memory QR factorization

Tags: matrix, julia, sparse-matrix, qr-decomposition, suitesparse

I am trying to numerically determine the rank of large matrices (around 50000 x 50000 64-bit floating point) using QR factorization with column pivoting.  Even when the matrix is somewhat sparse (density ~0.05), I am having trouble completing the factorization before running out of memory (499GB).  I am currently doing this in Julia with the [SparseArrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SparseArrays/) package (an interface for the [SuiteSparse](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) library), calling qr(A) or rank(A) where A is SparseMatrixCSC{Float64, Int64}.  Is there some way to reduce the memory usage since I only need R but not Q?  Are there other languages/libraries that could be more suitable for my purpose?

I also looked into other rank-revealing algorithms, but QR with pivoting seems to be the only numerically stable option.